# Grammatical construction regarding « consiste en ce que + S + V »

Tags: grammaire

I can’t get the grammatical construction of

> *La différence consiste en ce que cet article est plus robuste que l’autre.*

Can somebody help me out? Especially I get confused around the ***ce que*** part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lorsque les propositions subordonnées conjonctives dépendent d’un verbe utilisant une préposition, elles peuvent être introduites par « préposition + ce que ». Le démonstratif « ce » joue alors le rôle de tampon entre les deux éléments subordonnants.
Exemple :
Il s’attend à ce que je revienne (s’attendre à qqch)
Cela provient de ce qu’il n’y a pas de surveillance (provenir de qqch).

On pourrait aussi avoir la construction « préposition + le fait que ».
Exemple : cela provient du fait qu’il n’y a pas de surveillance.

Answer (score 4):

The sentence is more complex than it could be.

*Consister (en)* is here a copulative verb. It can be replaced by *être*:

> *La différence **est** que cet article est plus robuste que l'autre.*

or the more common:

> *La différence, **c'est que** cet article est plus robuste que l'autre.*

In "*La différence consiste **en ce que** cet article est plus robuste que l’autre*", ***que*** is turning the sentence *cet article est plus robuste que l'autre* into a "noun" equivalent (a noun phrase).

***En*** is the preposition used with *consister* (consists in) and the demonstrative ***ce*** (or the more formal *cela*) is required between *en* and *que* (*Que* can't be introduced by a preposition so *en que* is not grammatical). There are a few similar sequences: *de ce que*, *à ce que*.

Note that ***en ce que*** introduces here a *proposition conjonctive essentielle*, i.e. it can't be removed from the sentence without making it unintelligible: *La différence consiste.* (??). With this role, *en ce que* is mostly only used with *consister*, *différer*, *résider* and rarely *tenir*.

A literal translation would be:

> The difference consists **in that this** article is more robust than the other.

A couple of words make it more intelligible:

> The difference **lies in the fact that this** article is more robust than the other.

The sentence might be simplified that way:

> *La robustesse est ce qui distingue cet article de l'autre.*

Reference (bold is mine): *Le bon usage, 14<sup>e</sup> édition, 2008*

> *§ 1139 La proposition conjonctive essentielle*
>
> *Définition :*
>
> *Nous appelons conjonctives essentielles des propositions conjonctives qui remplissent dans la phrase (ou, éventuellement, dans une proposition) des fonctions nominales essentielles.*
>
> ***Mots de liaison** :*
>
> *a) C'est ordinairement la conjonction **que***
> *[...]*
> *b) **A ce que***
> *[...]*
> *c) **De ce que***
> *[...]*
> *d) **En ce que**, avec peu de verbes (consister, résider) :
> Un phénomène particulier, qui CONSISTAIT **EN CE QU**'À mesure que s'affaiblissait le bruit des prières de la rue se renforçait [...] un murmure de voix analogue (GRACQ, Aa château d'Argol, Pl., p. 79). — La différence entre les deux RÉSIDE **EN CE QUE** cette violence, pour Hong, suffit en tant que réalité abstraite (L. GOLDMANN, Pour une sociologie du roman, cit. Togeby, § 798,4). QB —
> L'usage préfère consister (ou résider) en ceci, que.*
> e) ***Sur ce que***
> *[...]*
> *f) **Comme quoi***
> *[...]*

This shows that ***en ce que*** is a single grammatical unit (a *locution conjonctive de subordination*) so shouldn't be parsed as [en] [ce que].

Answer (score 3):

The hard part of the sentence is the rather formal locution [*"en ce que"*](https://www.wordreference.com/fren/en%20ce%20que). It means "in the sense that", "inasmuch as". Here's the sentence from WordReference, with a translation:

> Cet administrateur est exemplaire **en ce qu'**il fait toujours passer l'intérêt général en premier.

> *This administrator is exemplary, **in the sense that** he always puts the public interest first.*

Another rather formal example:

> La Commission a enfreint les
> droits de défense des requérantes, **en ce qu'**elle les a empêchées d'user de la possibilité de retirer [...]

> *Commission infringed the applicants' right of defence **inasmuch as** it prevented them from relying on the possibility to withdraw [...]*

The variant "*en ceci que"* also exists. From [Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=auto&query=%22en+ceci+que%22):

> Leur utilisation est assez spécifique, **en ceci que** ce sont la taille et l'activité du bateau qui déterminent le type de produit à utiliser.

> *Their use is fairly specific, **in that** the size of the boat and its purpose determine the type of anti-fouling product to use.*

---

It can also be used with "*consiste en*", and basically the sentence means:

> The difference consists in the fact that this article is more robust than the other.

I think it's constructed that way because *"consister en"* must be followed by a noun or a noun phrase, and if you want to use a subordinate clause instead (*"cet article est plus robuste que l’autre"*), you have to use an elaborate construction.

Comment: Funny enough, this is the kind of sentence that seems transparent to me as someone who learned French through more formal and academic avenues... I think here I would translate it "consists in the fact that" (which yields a syntax as cumbersome in English as in French)

Comment: We say noun phrase, rather than nominal group.

Comment: @Lambie Ah, you're right. I first wrote "noun group", then googled it because it felt wrong and found the wikipedia page for "nominal group". But it seems it's only used in a very specific grammar theory.

Comment: Just a detail. I would parse this as: consiste en + ce que. ce que exists elsewhere, right? En ce qui me concerne, etc. :)

Comment: @Lambie Well yes, but if you parse it like that "*ce que*" has a different meaning. It should be followed by something like "*ce que cet article apporte par rapport à l'autre*". <ce que + subordinate clause> doesn't work on its own and in my opinion you need to parse it through <en ce que + subordinate clause> for it to make sense. I'll admit I'm not 100% of how this construction should be decomposed though. It's just my intuition, maybe Jlliagre's answer is more correct.